# How to close a tab page?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I have a tab control in a from1 and opened from2 in tabcontrol1. I want to clean tabcontrol1 when click on a button in form2 .
I try with these code but i can't .

---

open form2 in tabcontrol1 :

```
form2 sar = new form2();
sar.TopLevel = false;
TabPage tb = new TabPage();
tb.Controls.Add(sar);
sar.Parent = tb;
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tb);
sar.Show();
tabControl1.SelectTab(tb);
```

close tab with (button in form2):

```
private void exitbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.close();
    form1 f=new form1();
    f.cleantab();
    f.close();
}
```

and cleantab is (in form1) :

```
   public void cleantab()
   {
        tabcontrol1.tabpages.remove(tabcontrol1.selectedtab);
   }
```

but it doesn't work .

Comment: Please watch your spelling and post only real code. Without all those typos the closing should work fine. But of course you need a reference to the other form, meanig the __real__ one, not just another instance as you try now. Pass out a reference to the opening form when opening the 2nd form and keep it in the constructor !

Answer (score -1):

Use this code:

```
        private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        TabPage a;
        a=(TabPage)(this.Parent);
        TabControl b;
        b = (System.Windows.Forms.TabControl)a.Parent;
        b.TabPages.Remove(a);
    }
```

Comment: It very nice . Can you please explain this code?

Comment: We add the form you added to the tabpage, we get it and convert it to our own type, and export it for it.

Comment: excuse me . How can i run a function in form2 that it opened in tab control , from Form1 ?

Comment: Define a public function in the form2 and call it: form2.FunctionName